# boot camp error - "Windows cannot locate the disk and partition..."

Tags: macos, mac, windows, bootcamp, partition

I am trying to install Windows 10 on my Macbook Pro 16" 2019 model on latest Monterey. I downloaded the official windows 10 iso from the Microsoft website and ran boot camp with the iso - it worked fine, but upon beginning install it shoots out the error "Windows cannot locate the disk and partition specified in the unattended answer file's setting. Make sure the setting references a valid partition and restart the installation"; the boot camp partition is also no longer bootable.

There are few answers for this online but the ones that do seem to not pertain to me; they mostly involved either an extra or missing EFI disk, but neither of those applied. i tried to create bootable media using terminal, but after the windows logo it gives no display output.

I assume this is some sort of error with EFI and I noted my EFI disk did not have a Microsoft folder in it after the boot camp creation, but I'm not sure if that is created until after Windows is installed.

There is no external media or accessories plugged into the macbook.

I've reset nvram, sm,c etc to no result, ran First Aid multiple times on my disk, ran efi repair, and retried installing about 5-6 times. I did notice that boot camp partitions my afps container and not the ssd itself, which may be an issue.

If anyone has any idea what the solution here is, let me know!

Comment: Which  disk and partition are you trying to install Windows on? Can you provide the output from the command `diskutil list`?

Comment: @DavidAnderson boot camp assistant adds it to my macinstosh HD apfs container rather than partitioning the actual drive, which i assume may be the issue. i no longer have the partition, but i'll retry BCA and give you the output of diskutil list. here it is pre-boot camp: https://imgur.com/a/aX2h5TH